# FFMPEG 4.0 Opus Codec Not Enabled?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec

I just compiled and installed `ffmpeg-4.0` on my Kubunut 17.10 laptop, and and I'm getting an error when trying to do conversions using the opus components. It appears that opus is not enabled, and I get this error: `[opus @ 0x55b30ae65fc0] The encoder 'opus' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.` I added `-strict -2` to the command: `ffmpeg -strict -2 -y -i 40.mp4 40.opus`, but this doesn't seem to help.

I saw various people say that opus is included by default now, and others said that I needed to enable `--enable-libopus` during compilation. Every time I try to do this, it never seems to work though. I tried `./configure --enable-libopus` and `make --enable-libopus`, but the subroutines just acted with confusion.

Full output:

> `ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)
>     configuration: 
>     libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
>     libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
>     libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
>     libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
>     libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
>     libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
>     libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '40.mp4':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: isommp42
>       creation_time   : 2014-02-10T22:28:37.000000Z
>     Duration: 00:01:56.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 310 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 211 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2014-02-10T22:28:37.000000Z
>         handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> opus (native))
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   [opus @ 0x55dbad5801c0] The encoder 'opus' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
>   Average Intensity Stereo band: 0.0
>   Dual Stereo used: -nan%
>   Conversion failed!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to enable an experimental encoder, the compliance level has to be set on the output.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 40.mp4 -strict -2 40.opus
```

Comment: So this needs to be done every time? There isn't a way to enable this permanently? It worked BTW thanks!

Answer (score 4):

FFmpeg supports two Opus encoders:

- The experimental built-in encoder named `opus`,
- and `libopus` which depends on an external library and requires your `ffmpeg` to be built with `--enable-libopus`.

The native encoder `opus` is currently considered to be experimental, so it requires the output option `-strict experimental` (or the alias `-strict -2`).

`libopus` is very good encoder. Consider using it instead due to the current experimental status of `opus`, unless of course `opus` sounds good enough for your needs. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried `opus` yet. Writing this in a noisy environment so I can't do a listening test...)